# How to limit Python recursive combinations?

Tags: python, recursion, limit, combinations

I am currently trying to solve a how to get this piece of code to iterate through the different combinations of numbers below to equal 1200. Which works fine however I want the code to limit the numbers it explores and print the combinations with **only 5 different numbers**.

**E.g1 70, 260, 280, 290, 300 = 1200, uses 5 numbers. I want only these combinations.**

E.g2 10, 20, 30, 40, 110, 120, 160, 190, 240, 280 = 1200, uses 10 numbers. I don't want combinations with less than five or greater than 5, like this combination.

I don't know python too well, I feel like its a simple thing to do but with my limited coding knowledge I'm stuck.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
from itertools import combinations

def find_sum_in_list(numbers, target):
    results = []
    for x in range(len(numbers)):
        results.extend(
            [   
                combo for combo in combinations(numbers ,x)  
                    if sum(combo) == target    
            ]
    )
    print results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_sum_in_list([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290,300], 1200)
```

Thanks for any help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Two things: 1) I can't see how your function is recursive. It doesn't call itself. 2) If you only want combinations of 5 elements, why loop through different values of `x` and ask for combinations of `x` elements?

Comment: sorry this kind of math is beyond me. I tried putting 5 into x and it does work. I needed someone to point it out me before I could see my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but I don't think you need to do something recursive. I think this works.

```
from itertools import combinations

def find_sum_in_list(numbers, target, comboSize):
    results = []
    for combo in combinations(numbers, comboSize):
        if sum(combo) == target:
            results.append(combo)
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290,300]
    total = 1200
    comboSize = 5
    print find_sum_in_list(numbers, total, comboSize)
```

Comment: Thanks this code looks good too. You've written it very clearly too so its easier for me to understand.

Comment: @Metori No problem. You can definitely make it short with an answer like jack's but it sounded like understandably was important. Don't forget to upvote the answers you like and accept.

Comment: Only problem with this solution is the extra loop in the __main__ block. He only needs five-number combinations, and this gives him more.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) second argument is the number of items to combine. Try passing 5 instead of x

Answer (score 1):

You actually have almost what you need. The two lines in your list comprehension are pretty much everything, except for using '5' instead of 'x', as @Eric says. If you use filter to weed out all the combinations that don't have the right sum, then you end up with:

```
from itertools import combinations

def find_sum_in_list(numbers, target):
    return filter(lambda x: sum(x) == target, combinations(numbers, 5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print find_sum_in_list(range(10, 310, 10), 1200)
```

filter takes a function that takes each element of a list and returns true or false. I've passed into it an anonymous function that returns true only if the list sums to the target.

I also used range to generate your list of numbers, by counting from 10 to 310 by 10. range excludes the last element.

Comment: That's a clever method thanks. However I wanted to run other combinations of numbers some with duplicates so there might be two 10's or three 30's. I don't think I can do that with this method as its a range rather than discrete numbers.

Comment: You're welcome. You can use this find_sum_in_list implementation though. That isn't specific to my use of range.

Comment: Sorry my mistake :P. I wasn't reading your code closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not less recursive than your code, but I think it kind of does what you want.

```
import itertools

target_list = [
    10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 
    90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 
    160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 
    230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300
]

target_sum = 1200

def find_sum(target_list, num_elem, target_sum):
    combinations = itertools.combinations(target_list, num_elem)

    for comb in combinations:
        if sum(comb) == target_sum:
            print comb


find_sum(target_list, 5, target_sum)
```

Comment: I really like your method too. It seems very fast at spitting out the combinations.